# How would I make a real-time map programme showing all people on my site?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, maps

I want to use MySQL, jQuery and PHP - possibly either Google maps or my own vector with an overlay.

A demo of what I am trying to do: http://www2.clustrmaps.com/counter/maps.php?url=http://clustrmaps.com

I have a database which is updated about 200 records a second showing IPs of visitors. I want to know if there is a way I can then display it on a map - I was thinking: refresh the page and get the latest database results every 1 second. Then with those 50 records or so, use some sort of API IP matcher and then place them in co-ordinates on the map? Is there an easier way?

Appreciate some help. I will release my code freely on here once done.

Comment: this looks a classic use case for node.js

Comment: 200 records per second you'd kill your free google maps requests in 5 seconds. IP's aren't specific enough to get actual geolocation data either. What you'd need to do is use some sort of geolocation service, ie google and again the free version is very limited in the number of requests per day.

Comment: Your question is rather vague - do you have a specific thing you want to ask?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - no need to be quite so hipster. Ry Dahl just started it off, it's now kind of a big deal in it's own right. What are you are trying to do is very easily done by using nodejs, far more so than PHP.  Discounting a language because you don't like it's creator is a bit childish...

Comment: It's not Dahl. It is the startup mentality .. this guy speaks volumes on it.. http://www.realfreemarket.org/blog/2011/10/25/node-js-is-vb6/

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer per se but some ideas.

Whatever code you have putting the visitor IP's in the database should also do a GeoIP lookup and put the `result` + `ip address` in a cache of some kind (memcache, redis, apc if its on a single server), and give the cached item a TTL of a few minutes.

If you are using only PHP then have an endpoint on the server which returns an array of lat/lons by reading the items in the cache.

In the browser, send a request to the endpoint every x seconds and draw the items on a map.

There is a lot of room for making the above more efficient but it should be a good starting point and will avoid hammering your DB needlessly.

For GeoIP have a look at [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/home), they have a free IP address to country/city product with PHP api.